# Create location-based marker with csv and svg in Here Maps

Tags: csv, svg, here-api

i am currently trying to create markers on a map by using a csv file and a location pin in svg-format.

I use an example code from Here Maps to have a solid starting point but it seems to me that there is even more work to do. 
I stored both my CSV and SVG file on my computer, so i tried to insert a local url path to my code. The CSV file is called "han_parks". It basically has just 4 comlumns right now: "Name", "Lat", "Lng", "Typ". I am confused because the code asks for **rows** instead of columns but it worked on an example on the Here Maps site. So here is the code basis for my CSV file and Geolocation:

```
let provider = new H.datalens.RawDataProvider({
dataUrl: "file:///C:\Users\oem\Desktop\MyName\WIXCode\HereMaps\CSV\han_parks.csv" + Date.now(),
dataToFeatures: (data) => {
    let parsed = helpers.parseCSV(data);
    let features = [];
    let row = null;
    let feature = null;

    for (let i = 1, l = parsed.length; i < l; i++) {
        row = parsed[i];
        feature = {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [Number(row[2]), Number(row[1])]
            },
            'properties': {
                'Name': row[0],
                'Type':  row[3]
            }
        };
        features.push(feature);
    }
    return features;
},
featuresToRows: (features) => {
    let rows = [], feature;
    for (let i = 0, l = features.length; i < l; i++) {
        feature = features[i];
        rows.push([{
                lat: feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lng: feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
            },
            feature.properties.Name,
            feature.properties.Typ
        ]);
    }
    return rows;
}
});
let layer = new H.datalens.ObjectLayer(provider, {
    pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,

    rowToMapObject: function (data) {
        let coordinates = data[0];
        let Name = data[1];
        return new H.map.Marker(coordinates);
    },

    rowToStyle: function (data, zoom) {
        if (!venueIcons[data[4]]) { return }
        let icon = H.datalens.ObjectLayer.createIcon(venueIcons[data[4]],
            {size: 30 * pixelRatio});
        return {icon};
    }
});
```

The SVG marker is even more of a hassle for me. The code for the SVGs used for the Here Maps example  are really extensive and i dont know if i am doing it right at all. Since it is also stored locally, i tried the same approach like before with the CSV file. The name of the marker is location_pin.

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

let venueIcons = {};

venueIcons['Park'] = `<svg xmlns:xlink="http:///C:\Users\oem\Desktop\MyName\WIXCode\HereMaps\location_pin.svg" viewBox="0 0 34.58 36.33" width="30" height="30"></svg>`;

Object.assign(window, {venueIcons});

}());
```

I got several ideas why it wont work but i am actually a noob at coding. I expect several errors within the code. This project means a lot to me so i am looking forward to your help and input!

If you want to get an insight into the Here Maps example, here´s the link:

[Here Maps Geovisualization](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/geovisualization/technology_markers/markers-csv-provider)

Best regards,

Daud

Comment: In general browsers have restrictions with respect to accessing any local csv files (for e.g C:// ) , you should try putting the file on a webserver or have a web server on your local machine and try providing the url of the file then (e.g http://localhost/folder/file)

Comment: @JithinKrishnan thanks for the reply. I am sorry, i forgot to mention that i develop my website on WIX code and the whole code is stored on the side within an html iframe. So in fact, i dont really use a folder on my laptop to store my code.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood but from the code shared above the file being referenced is 'file:///C:\Users\oem\Desktop\MyName\WIXCode\HereMaps\CSV\han_parks.csv' on you local folder ? Are you able to access it using http/https protocol ?

Comment: @JithinKrishnan No, you were right about that. I am not able to access the csv file on that way. Now i created a folder with the xammp/phpmyadmin method and put the csv file there but it still won´t work. There is still something i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the data lens library is deprecated now and is no longer supported. The recommendation would be to migrate to HERE JS API 3.1 with using Markers to add objects on the map.